# simple json dumps function with unicode

Tags: python, unicode, simplejson

Here is a sample run of simple json using python2.4 version

```
>>> 
>>> orig='{"key1":"Val", "key2":"val2"}'
>>> origDict = simplejson.loads(orig)
>>> origDict
{'key2': 'val2', 'key1': 'Val'}
>>> origDict['key2'] = '\xe4\xbd\xa0\xe5\xa5\xbd'
>>> simplejson.dumps(origDict)
'{"key2": "\\u4f60\\u597d", "key1": "Val"}'
```

The dumps functions is replacing the byte string with the unicode version. Is there a way to make it not do that and just return '{"key2": "\xe4\xbd\xa0\xe5\xa5\xbd", "key1": "Val"}' ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Pass `ensure_ascii=False` and encode manually after.

Comment: Thanks! that worked..but what do you mean by encode after. It was returning the byte string I wanted. >>> simplejson.dumps(origDict, ensure_ascii=False)
'{"key2": "\xe4\xbd\xa0\xe5\xa5\xbd", "key1": "Val"}'

Comment: It's supposed to return a `unicode`, which you'd have to encode as UTF-8 after.

Comment: It shows as str on my system! 
>>> origDict
{'key2': '\xe4\xbd\xa0\xe5\xa5\xbd', 'key1': 'Val'}
>>> type(simplejson.dumps(origDict, ensure_ascii=False))
<type 'str'>

Is it because the dict does not have any non utf8 chars?

Comment: yeah could be. Thanks anyway!

Comment: After taking a second look at your code, I'm surprised it's outputting those Unicode escape sequences, since you aren't using `unicode`s.

Comment: I am using the latest version of simplejson compatible with python 2.4
python-simplejson-2.0.9-8.el5.i386

Comment: Although the above does work for unicode text, it also returns an error when is meets some characters such as '\xe4'. I'm getting the following error:  
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\xe4' in position 1614: character maps to <undefined>

Any ideas?