# Why isn't my text file being written in UTF-8 encoding in Python and how and I read it properly?

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8

> ## About saving in UTF-8

I have a python script which consumes Twitter API and saves some tweets in JSON structures.

When it comes to text containing characters like *á, é, í, ó or ú* I won't get that text saved properly but replaced by a pattern like *`\u00f1`*:

This is my while script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
import twitter
import json
from api.search import *
from  api.tpt import *
from tweet.tweet import *
from time import *
WORLD_WOE_ID = 23424900

trendingTopics = startTrendsDictionary()
twitterAPI = createAPIConsumer()
print "Twitter API started" 


while True:

    mexican_trends = twitterAPI.trends.place(_id=WORLD_WOE_ID)
    print "Current trends fetched"
    with open ('../files/trends/trends '+strftime("%c"), 'w') as trendsFile:
        trendsFile.write(json.dumps(mexican_trends,indent=1))
        print "Current trends at +- {t} saved".format(t=strftime("%c"))

    statuses = harvestTrendingTopicTweets(twitterAPI,trendingTopics,100,10)
    print "Harvest done"
    with open('../files/tweets/unclassified '+strftime("%c"), 'w') as statusesFile:
        statusesFile.write(json.dumps(statuses,indent=1).encode('utf-8'))
        print "File saved"
    print "We're going to wait in order not to fed up Twitter API"
    sleep(2400)
    print "OK, it was enough waiting, here we go again"
```

I thought that both:

- `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`
- `.encode('utf-8'))`

Will solve it but they don't.

> ## About reading in UTF-8

When it comes to read, I'm trying:

```
import json

with open('file', 'r', buffering=1) as f:

    tweetsJSON = json.load(f)

    for category in tweetsJSON:

        for trend in tweetsJSON[category]:
            for t in tweetsJSON[category][trend]:

                print t['text']
                print
```

In this case, printed to console, **I can see all those letters displayed properly*.*

So, why when I open the saved files with a text editor (Sublime Text, in my case) they won't look ok?

Comment: possible duplicate of [simple json dumps function with unicode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9883464/simple-json-dumps-function-with-unicode)

Comment: Have you tried setting your text editor to a proper encoding?